# Rails acronym inflection splitting mid-acronym

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use the scaffold generator to a model and controller called 'RSVP'. I was hoping that defining the inflection would be enough to make it create an `rsvps_controller.rb` with an RSVPController class and an `RSVP` model with an `RSVPs` table. I'd also find RsvpController and Rsvp acceptable.

Unfortunately it seems to have split 'RSVP' into 'RSV P', so `rails generate scaffold RSVP ...` has created an array of different spellings, including rsv_ps_controller, RsvPsController, and rSVPs. The only acceptable result is the model file called rsvp.rb with an Rsvp class inside it.

Is there a proper way to achieve the desired result? I'm using Rails 4.1.4

My config/initializers/inflections.rb looks like:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'RSVP'
  inflect.irregular 'RSVP', 'RSVPs'
end
```

I've tried with all combinations of those two (ie. both singularly as well as both defined). Both seem to get the same results.

```
> bundle exec rails generate scaffold RSVP account:references ...
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20140918213359_create_rSVPs.rb
      create    app/models/rsvp.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/rsvp_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/rSVPs.yml
      invoke  resource_route
       route    resources :rSVPs
      invoke  scaffold_controller
      create    app/controllers/rsv_ps_controller.rb
      invoke    erb
      create      app/views/rsv_ps
      create      app/views/rsv_ps/index.html.erb
      create      app/views/rsv_ps/edit.html.erb
      create      app/views/rsv_ps/show.html.erb
      create      app/views/rsv_ps/new.html.erb
      create      app/views/rsv_ps/_form.html.erb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/controllers/rsv_ps_controller_test.rb
      invoke    helper
      create      app/helpers/rsv_ps_helper.rb
      invoke      test_unit
      create        test/helpers/rsv_ps_helper_test.rb
      invoke    jbuilder
      create      app/views/rsv_ps/index.json.jbuilder
      create      app/views/rsv_ps/show.json.jbuilder
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/rsv_ps.js.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/rsv_ps.css.scss
      invoke  scss
      create    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss
```

Comment: You could call it a `Response` instead of `RSVP`...

Comment: I'm considering that, but I thought it should be possible to have an acronym like this as a model name.

Answer (score 1):

The doc for the [ActiveSupport::Inflector::Inflections.acronym](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-acronym) method indicates that you should add an acronym entry for both the singular and pluralized form.

That implies the the following should work.  However, this still doesn't seem to work for me.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'RSVP'
  inflect.acronym 'RSVPs'
end
```

From the doc:

```
  # Note: Acronyms that are passed to +pluralize+ will no longer be
  # recognized, since the acronym will not occur as a delimited unit in the
  # pluralized result. To work around this, you must specify the pluralized
  # form as an acronym as well:
  #
  #    acronym 'API'
  #    camelize(pluralize('api')) # => 'Apis'
  #
  #    acronym 'APIs'
  #    camelize(pluralize('api')) # => 'APIs'
```